# Youtube browser based upload API, which channel it goes to? where is the video key?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

With reference to this page...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading#Browser_based_uploading

On point 6 of the very last potion of the page it says...

`The user selects his video and submits the form, sending his video and the upload token directly to YouTube. YouTube verifies the token is valid and adds the video to the user's YouTube channel.`

By `user's YouTube channel` does it mean "uploader's" or "site owner's" channel? Should be site owner right?

Another thing is ...

`During this process, YouTube assigns the video a unique ID, which will be used to identify the video on YouTube.`

How can I get that unique ID so that I can edit title and description of that video via API in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of the process here
http://www.googlecodesamples.com/youtube/php/YouTubeVideoApp/index.php

On this example you can see that once you successfully upload a file the youtube ID of the video is returned.